# Roslyn: Get Compiler-generated names for Anonymous Types

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Say I have the following code:

```cs
using System;
public class Class {    
    public static void Main() {
      Func<bool> f = () => true;
    }
}
```

The compiler generates an anonymous class and function for the lambda expression. For example, SharpLab.io shows:

```cs
public class Class
{
    [Serializable]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <>c
    {
        public static readonly <>c <>9 = new <>c();

        public static Func<bool> <>9__0_0;

        internal bool <Main>b__0_0()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Func<bool> func = <>c.<>9__0_0 ?? (<>c.<>9__0_0 = new Func<bool>(<>c.<>9.<Main>b__0_0));
    }
}
```

How can I use Roslyn to associated the `LambdaExpressionSyntax` of the lambda function, with the generated `<>c.<Main>b__0_0` function name?

I understand these generated names are unstable, and not documented. Still, I would like to query them.

Comment: Next time when you compile this code the name <>c.<Main>b__0_0 will be different name. You can't forecast the name the compiler will select. It is random.

Comment: What's your goal for querying them?

Comment: I am writing a small DSL within C# for composing game logic together, using generators. This is heavily a research project -- not business software, or anything that needs to be maintained, so I'm fine with relying on unstable features of the compiler.

Essentially this system boils down to persisting the state of a running generator. I would like to be able to reason about the names of lambdas to help with that process.

Comment: These names aren't random at all, actually. The numbers are just based on the index-location of the lambda in the file and containing method. But I'd prefer to just be able to grab the name directly with Roslyn, rather than backward-engineering the name-generation function.

Comment: It's also perfectly fine if they change on every compilation -- that's expected. This process runs after every compilation.

Comment: @Kleptine did you find any solution? I am actually facing the exact same issue and I really do want to avoid reverse engineering that, since it is not only expensive, but also very complicated as indices may change when the method is for example async.

Comment: @Twenty No, unfortunately not. I ended up having to ban lambdas in the analyzed code paths. It's worth noting that while Lambdas are indexed by their position in the file, Methods are not -- they have a unique name.

So in our system, we replaced all lambdas with Func<> method references. "ClassA::Func1". It's not great, honestly, and is one of the reasons we abandoned this overall approach (one reason among many).

Comment: One thing you may consider if this is really critical for your use case, is to use auto-generated comments to tag lambdas. ie. `/* 42 */ (x) => x*2`.  This can be done with Roslyn fairly automatically (add a comment with a unique id if none exists), and then you can read that ID back by looking at the attached Trivia from the lambda. It does feel like a bit of a hack, but we did this for yield statements, to track state even when functions are changed.

Comment: @Kleptine Thanks a lot for your response, however I actually found a way which might be sufficient for my use case. You are correct that the names are seemingly generated by random. However, they appear to be in the exact same order in the user code and the generated code. There are, as always, some edge cases which require some more tinkering. This however, only works if you don't require the actual full name of the generated method in roslyn.

Comment: Glad you got it working! We ended up needing the actual full names, and more-over needed a stable name, invariant to code changes, which was the bigger issue. 

BTW, in case you haven't found it, SharpLab.io was absolutely instrumental for debugging this sort of thing. It's very easy to poke around how the C# gets decompiled.